# How much memory can/will w3wp use

Tags: iis, memory, memory-leaks, w3wp, w3wp.exe

On Win2k12, running IIS8, with 12GB of ram, how much memory will a single w3wp process use with no other pressures.

I am attempting to isolate where I have an issue. It seems like there is a leak somewhere since it grows to about 10GB and then crashes and starts up again. It usually hovers between 800MB-2GB. Then, all of the sudden, it starts increasing over a 2-5 minute period and it crashes.

As I begin to isolate I was wondering, all things being equal, how much would the process use up with no other pressure - just one site on this server. Similar to the way SQL Server will use up all the ram, if you let it, will w3wp do the same?

Comment: For app pool which doesn't have any application assigned would normally take memory in range of 50-100MB. 10GB is abnormally high which is definite case of memory leakage.

Comment: To clarify, there is one web application running in the app pool (.net 4.5)